# MongoDB $text $search returns exact phrase instead of contains

Tags: mongodb, mern

[image: I]

I have this data on my local MongoDB and I want to do a search on `title` field containing "the".

when I used this code it returned an empty array:

```
postsArray = await posts.find({ $text: { $search: "the" } }).toArray()
```

However if I entered the exact `title`, it returned the correct result

```
postsArray = await posts.find({ $text: { $search: "the game" } }).toArray()
```

according to the documentation, the first code should also return the same result,

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$text` search will not match **the** and **and** words, There is an instruction about Match Operation:

> [**Stop Words**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#stop-words):
>
> *The `$text` operator ignores language-specific stop words, such as    **the** and **and** in English.*

---

Let's take an example of different words and it should work:

Assume we have the below document:

```
{ "title": "Good Morning" }
```

**Query 1:** Search for "good" word:

```
{ $text: { $search: "good" } }
```

> **Result:** [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l-MchGem4KU)
>
> ```
> { "title": "Good Morning" }
> ```

**Query 2:** Search for "good morning" word:

```
{ $text: { $search: "good morning" } }
```

> **Result:** [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f4xiiPE9t3d)
>
> ```
> { "title": "Good Morning" }
> ```